# macOS/SpriteKit: unsupported surface format: LA08 - what error is this?

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, skview

This is from a macOS 10.12.6 app (Xcode 9.3; Swift 4), and it appears when the app starts running: I get seven of these in the console.

This is the storyboard scene:

[image: Storyboard]

In my viewController, I have an outlet for the scrollView; I create an SKView, and add it to the scrollView. (This is the complete code).

```
let skView: SKView = SKView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2000, height: 1400))

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        scrollView.contentView.addSubview(skView)
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

(The purpose of this is to have a SpriteKit view I can scroll; this only seems to work with an imageView embedded in the scrollview.)

This error seems to have no effect on the app or how content is displayed; but I'm curious to know what is is and if I can get rid of it.

Comment: Did you do a full clean?  It is claiming your drawing surface is not supported

Comment: I have, and the error persists. I've reconstructed the code in a new project, and it builds without errors, so this remains a mystery. But thanks, that helps me out. (For now, I'm treating this as a weird one-off and shall ignore it unless it happens again.)

Comment: The latest version of XCode seems buggier than ever.  I find myself constantly having to do disk repair to get my application to work correctly

Comment: Its not a bug, the imageView and its image residing inside the Sprite do not conform to the expected format.

Comment: Thank you. I've not pursued that route; but it's good to know.